# Ionic2 - how to run two applications implemented within one codebase

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 application, which gets more and more complex, so there is a need to split it into different apps (**gui** and **service**) based on the same code.
The gui app will contain the functionality of service app, but in bigger scenario, it will connect to this service, which will be running on remote server.
I have found that there is a `angular-cli.json` file, which contains specification for my gui app like:

```
  "apps": [
        {
              ...
              "main": "app/main.ts",
              ...
        }
  ]
```

It is a table of apps in fact, so I thought I could create a separate entry for my service app, e.g.:

```
        {
              ...
              "name": "MyService",
              "main": "service/service.ts",
              ...
        }
```

and run it on server using some command like:

```
 ionic MyService
```

I would compare this need to running Java application using different Main classes.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an API as a shared service for the UIs. The bulk of the logic will be moved to the backend and the UI will be a thin layer managing the UI logic.

If you plan to use the same technology/language, you should be able to reuse the current services and expose(group them logically) with API endpoints. That might not be straight forward depending on how entangled that code with the rest of the system. You want to pull out the seam or bounded context that is least depended on if you can. Also other thing to think about is where you are going to get the most benefit from separating the code, rather than just splitting things for the sake of it.

Comment: I want to create API for the backend module. When using backend together with frontend, it will be just called by the app internally, but when backend will be running on server, there will be websocket connection. That's it. My problem is that I don't know how to configure the Ionic project - all the jsons  etc. to be able to run gui or service app in the same (project) directory using commands like 'ionic run MyGuiApp' or 'ionic run MyServiceApp' and that's my question.

Comment: I don't think you can run them in same project. That will become complex to debug and maintain code. The intent is to separate the concerns and code maintainability.